# Node Crashes when Queues are Opened and Closed Several Times

Tags: node.js, crash, ibm-mq

I'm trying to implement a service which receives messages from a tcp socket, puts them  on one of two permanent queues, polls for replies on a dynamically created queue, and sends replies back over the socket. This works fine with one socket. However, there is a requirement the the tcp connection end after a fixed duration, so that the tcp client needs to reconnect. This works a few times, but the forth, fifth, ... MQ connection or queue setup crashes the server. The same happens if I try to serve more then two clients concurrently. This is NOT a E_CONN_RESET which results in an uncatchable error on the server (btw I don't understand why it is not possible to catch this event!). I suppose that IBM's client dll creates new threads from time to time which node cannot handle.

My machine runs Windows 10 Pro (latest updates) and has IBM MQ 9.2.1, node 15.11.0, and the current ibmmq node library installed.
Here is what node prints before it ends:

```
#
# Fatal error in , line 0
# Check failed: result.second.
#
#
#
#FailureMessage Object: 0000008001AFDBB0
 1: 00007FF6D5C54BFF napi_wrap+159807
 2: 00007FF6D5B76CFF v8::CFunction::ReturnInfo+2271
 3: 00007FF6D6808522 V8_Fatal+162
 4: 00007FF6D6279F6D v8::internal::BackingStore::Reallocate+653
 5: 00007FF6D64D2F09 v8::ArrayBuffer::GetBackingStore+137
 6: 00007FF6D5AFF146 v8::internal::OrderedHashTable<v8::internal::OrderedHashMap,2>::OrderedHashTable<v8::internal::OrderedHashMap,2>+27766
 7: 00007FF6D6498ACF v8::internal::Builtins::builtin_handle+316399
 8: 00007FF6D6498054 v8::internal::Builtins::builtin_handle+313716
 9: 00007FF6D6498355 v8::internal::Builtins::builtin_handle+314485
10: 00007FF6D6498193 v8::internal::Builtins::builtin_handle+314035
11: 00007FF6D6573E2D v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+456973
12: 00007FF6D650C6B2 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+33170
13: 00007FF6D650C6B2 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+33170
14: 00007FF6D650C6B2 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+33170
15: 00007FF6D650C6B2 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+33170
16: 00007FF6D650C6B2 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+33170
17: 00007FF6D650C6B2 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+33170
18: 00007FF6D650C6B2 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+33170
19: 00007FF6D650C6B2 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+33170
20: 00007FF6D650C6B2 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+33170
21: 00007FF6D6504E89 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+2409
22: 00007FF6D650C6B2 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+33170
23: 00007FF6D650C6B2 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+33170
24: 00007FF6D650C6B2 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+33170
25: 00007FF6D650C6B2 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+33170
26: 00007FF6D650A36E v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+24142
27: 00007FF6D6509F5C v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+23100
28: 00007FF6D63D3BBD v8::internal::Execution::CallWasm+1645
29: 00007FF6D63D342F v8::internal::Execution::Call+191
30: 00007FF6D64C6737 v8::Function::Call+615
31: 00007FF6D5C7C2EB node::CallbackScope::~CallbackScope+1691
32: 00007FF6D5C73834 napi_wrap+285812
33: 00007FF6D5B08273 v8::internal::MicrotaskQueue::microtasks_policy+20675
34: 00007FF6D5B08DED v8::internal::MicrotaskQueue::microtasks_policy+23613
35: 00007FF6D5B03719 v8::internal::MicrotaskQueue::microtasks_policy+1385
36: 00007FF6D5C9619B uv_tty_set_vterm_state+9227
37: 00007FF6D5CAC08C uv_loop_init+924
38: 00007FF6D5CAC39A uv_run+202
39: 00007FF6D5C7B6C4 node::SpinEventLoop+308
40: 00007FF6D5BA34B7 EVP_CIPHER_CTX_buf_noconst+51927
41: 00007FF6D5C1BB9B node::Start+283
42: 00007FF6D5A4832C RC4_options+346668
43: 00007FF6D6A8683C v8::internal::compiler::RepresentationChanger::Uint32OverflowOperatorFor+153276
44: 00007FF8575C7034 BaseThreadInitThunk+20
45: 00007FF858762651 RtlUserThreadStart+33
```

I could try to spawn a new process instead of running the code always within the same node instance which is likely to work. However, I think it is important to know what happens anyway, and if there is a way to avoid such crashes. In particular, although nothing crashed so far if there is only a single connection which is not reniewed, I think some paranoia should be in place: can I trust that node.js (ibmmq.js) will not crash with only three queues accessed? Has somebody an idea about this?

Related to this, I could observe that a test routine crashed too after trying to access a dynamic queue a couple of times which does not exist any more.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly because of an issue in the ref-napi dependency. See https://github.com/node-ffi-napi/ref-napi/issues/47 for example.

A PR got merged in that repo yesterday that appears to resolve it, so the ibmmq package will get updated soon to reference that new version